# Why PHP7 doesn't use just Exceptions but a mix of Errors and Exceptions?

Tags: php

From [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/language.errors.php7.php)

> (In PHP7) Instead of reporting errors through the traditional error reporting mechanism used by PHP 5, *most errors* are now reported by throwing Error exceptions.

Question 1) Is there a specific reason why the PHP core developers decided to use Exceptions for most of the errors an not for all?

Look at these "tests":

This produces "old style" PHP error:

```
preg_match('/@/', array());
```

This produces an Exception with Class "Error"

```
this_function_does_not_exist();
```

Then there is the Exception with Class "ErrorException"

3 different kind of errors. Beside these there are also the [SPL Exceptions](http://php.net/manual/en/spl.exceptions.php)

I feel quite confused by these many types of error but my understanding is limited.
Question 2) What are the reasons for so many types of error?

Comment: Historical baggage, probably?

Comment: because PHP is the programming equivalent of the human body. it's evolved over many years and is full of bad design decisions and historical artifacts. and yet, much like the human body, can accomplish incredible things in spite of all that historical garbage.

Comment: I don't mind people down voting me but please explain me why. I'm not here for score but to learn and it's already hard enough without being turned down. Thank you.

Comment: I think that the major reason for that was just to allow the recover of fatal errors. This is now possible: but if you need more, and convert any notice and warning into exception, you can do that with `set_error_handler`. If that would be the default behavior, it would be a (too) big b.c. Maybe it's something to do in the next major version

Comment: @Barmar I've thought of that too but it doesn't make much sense because the change is already not BC in some cases. Ex. `this_function_does_not_exist();` produces an Error in php5 not an Exception . So I don't understand. Maybe they have plans to slowly move towards an "all exceptions" strategy in the future?